# Last three Lines of text file

Tags: c#

I need a little help! I cannot figure out how to take the last three lines of a file and store each to a separate string. An array would work too if possible.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(myfile);
```

If someone could use an array for this, how would I get only the last three lines. Please keep note that I do not know the length of the file!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This seems a little too simple....

### Update

In case the length of the array is less than 3 in size.  This should either print the last three lines based on count, or less than three lines if i == -1

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(myFile)
// Get the last three lines
int count = 0;
for (int i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
    count++;
    if (count == 3) 
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only possible problem here is if `lines.Length` is `< 3`

Comment: I would hardly say that's an edge case - the OP also stated he didn't know how many lines there were. I suppose you could just wrap it in a try/catch?

Answer (score 3):

```
var last3lines = lines.Skip(lines.Length - 3).ToArray();
```

Comment: OP wants the lines to go into separate strings. You're putting them into an array.

Comment: last3lines[0], last3lines[1] and last3lines[2] are very separate strings. They also happened to be inside an array. But that fact is not preventing them from being separate.

Answer (score 1):

For a way that does not require you to load all lines from the file in a big array with `ReadAllLines`, but just reads them a line at a time, keeping only the last (3) ones read, you can do:

```
var threeLines = new string[3];
var nLines = 0;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(myFile))
{
    var ndx = nLines % 3;
    threeLines[ndx] = line;
    nLines++;
}
```

Also, this will not crash if you have less then 3 lines in your input.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Math.Min(nLines, 3); i++)
    Console.WriteLine(threeLines[i]);
```

Or to get them in order of last, last-1, last-2:

```
for (var i = Math.Min(nLines, 3); i > 0; i--)
    Console.WriteLine(threeLines[i-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inefficient but it works: `lines.Reverse().Take(3).Reverse()`

Alternative:

```
line1 = lines[lines.length-3] // Third to last
line2 = lines[lines.length-2]
line3 = lines[lines.length-1] // Last line
```